# about database and remote connections

Tags: c#, connection

i have some questions about databases and remote connections..

i've made an application that connects to sql server db on local machine then i published the app. and installed it on other machine..

was very bad when i realised that the application won't work except that there are sql server instance on that machine.. :/

am thinking now to use access db instead of Sql Server..
but i don't know if i had to install access on every machine to make the app. work ?? or just the access db file "mdb" is enough to connect and react with data on that db ??

and if i had to install access on the pc that hold the database, do i had to install it on client mashines too in order to access the db on server with remote connection ??

answering these question will rly help me too much.

thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't have to install Access. ADO.Net will take care of connection.
Also you can use SQL Server Compact Edition. With adding some Dlls to your project, you don't need sql server installed on client machine as well.

Comment: u mean i don't need to install access on client machine or server machine, just ".mdb" file and go on with remote connection and quering the db file using c# application ??

Comment: @Shenno: Yes, I just deployed an application which uses .mdb file as its database without having to install MS-Access on the client machine.

Comment: Just notice that the client machine HAS to have the appropriate .NET Framework installed.